# Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value image.svg

Tags: image, thymeleaf, src

I was able to load an image with thymeleaf with this clause : `th:src="@{/images/EmptyChat.svg}"`
But, now I'm getting this error :
Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value image.svg
How can I resolve this problem please?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the problem by converting the svg to png image.